# when "same" refers to plural group... IS or ARE?

Tags: grammar

Which is correct below -- the IS or the ARE?

I hereby certify that I have examined **the accompanying financial statements and supplementary data** of Shores, LLC, and, to the best of my knowledge and belief, **the same** IS/ARE complete and accurate.

(bold added to emphasize subjects)

Comment: Why not just say "they"? "Same" sounds silly. Have your read Garner's "Legal Writing in Plain English" and his "Dictionary of Modern Legal English"?

Comment: The excerpt is from an accounting document I had to proofread, and -- except for conjugating the verbs -- I was not allowed to change the wording. :(

Answer (score 1):

statements and data = plural so "are" should be used.

Comment: Thanks! Just to confirm -- this means "same" is a plural noun in this case?

Comment: @Shane: The cited usage of ***the same*** is just pompous legalese - any normal speaker (or writer) would just use ***these***. But ***the same*** isn't inherently either singular or plural. It depends on the plurality of whatever it references, which may be a matter of opinion anyway. For example, *I have examined the fish and chips, and to the best of my knowledge **it** is safe to eat*. Or ***they** are safe*, if you see them as separate things, or ***the same** is/are* if you're a fusty lawyer.

Comment: @ FumbleFingers: Exactly. And even the supposed guru on Legal English style in America, Bryan Garner, says that this type of legalese with "same" and the like is simply pompous and sounds silly, so saying that it is the preferred legal style makes no sense.